# How can I put in charts with swift 3 Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts

I'm beginner swift developer. Just for a week now I've been trying to implement some kind of chart into my app. I know `Swift 4` and `Xcode 9` are already out but I'm still using `Swift 3` and `Xcode 8`. I've read a lot of tutorials and different pages but still I'm not able to find any working ones. All examples are either too old or for swift 4. I've learned about using `Cocoapods` and other frameworks such as `Firebase` or `Alamofire` work just fine.

Please let me know if you can help me with finding some chart library that actually works as it is supposed to.

Comment: 1) How are we supposed to recommend a chart library if you don't tell us what you want to achieve?
2) This sparks a discussion, which is not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Asking for a library, tutorial is not a valid topic here.  This topic should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get things materialistic and kick off, for building charts in iOS try [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library. One of the best third-party libs out there.

Or check **[this list](https://github.com/ameizi/awesome-ios-chart)** for even more awesome iOS charts libraries.